# OSX El Capitan Disk Utility resized the recovery partition

Tags: macos, partitioning, vmware-fusion

I'm running a VMWare Fusion VM of OSX El Capitan, VMWare refused to allow me to assign more than 40GB disk when creating the VM. 
So I decided to boot up Disk Utility from the recovery and resize the disk.

I resized the partition to my desired size and clicked accept, however it seems to have resized the hidden recovery disk instead.

Now I'm unable to resize any partitions and have a massive recovery partition.
It's also seemed to use standard GPT instead of using any Core Storage (so diskutil cs commands won't work).

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be some bug with OSX's new Disk Utility, possibly the combination with VMWare disk images.

To fix:

1. Boot into the OS as normal.
2. Open a terminal.
3. Repair the disk `diskutil repairVolume /dev/disk0s3` (where disk0s3 is your volume)
4. Verify the disk `diskutil verifyVolume /dev/disk0s3`
5. Resize the partition `diskutil resizeVolume /dev/disk0s3 650M`
6. Boot into the recovery mode
7. Open the terminal, don't use the Disk Utility
8. Resize the actual disk `diskutil resizeVolume /dev/disk0s2 200G` (where disk0s2 is the actual disk you want to resize, 200G is your size)

Answer (score 0):

I too encountered this problem with a more recent version of OSX, finding the disk utility to be crippled.
I discovered that gparted live ISO could be booted and move the recovery partition to the end of the disk. Then I rebooted into OSX and used the disk utility to extend the partition and grow the file system.